# a substitute for static in C++

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, static

Is there a way to get a map or a list in c++ to keep its old entries with several calls without being defined as static ?
I'm using a multi map, the problem is that if it's static, it returns only the first entry else I just end up with an empty map.

```
here's the code :

    typedef struct mystruct_1 {
    std::string         _name;
    int             _nb_ev;
    int             _nb_oc;
    std::list<mystruct_2>   _ev;
    mystruct_1() {}
} mystruct_1_t;



typedef struct mystruct_2 {
    int    _id;
    int    _nbs;
    char **_t;
    mystruct_2() {}
} mystruct_2_t;


myclass::method_1(){
static std::map<std::string,mystruct_1> _Pat;
static std::multimap<std::string,mystruct_2> map_occ;

switch( myswitch ) {
            case _P_1 :
        {
         while( condition_1 ){
            mystruct_1 *p =  new mystruct_1();
            _Pat.insert ( std::pair<std::string ,mystruct_1>(p->_name,*p) );
            }   
        }
        break;
            case _P_2 :
        {
        std::string name;
        while( condition_2 ){
            mystruct_2 *line=new mystruct_2();
            map_occ.insert ( std::pair<std::string ,mystruct_2>(name,*line) );  
        }
        break;
       case _P_3 :
        {
        // here I need to get what was stored
        myclass::method_2();

        }
        break;
       default :
        // something else ;

}
}
myclass::method_2(){
//uses what was stored in the map and in the multimap 
}
```

Comment: Code or it didn't happen.

Comment: Can you show your code? It sounds like you are repeatedly creating new maps and lists.

Comment: C++03 or C++11? And with which compiler and system?

Comment: you're asking for state throughout calls. if you want something like a function that can do that, create a [functor](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, always assume the latest. Unless specified otherwise.

Comment: Ever heard of a data member?

Comment: Are you passing by copy, or by reference or are you using a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have created some sort of "C with classes" monster.

Those static variables should be members of your class, for example:

```
class foo
{
     public:
       std::string m_String; // Not defined globally or at file scope!
};
```

This way whenever you change m_String for the same instance of foo, it will retain its state.